# Does YouTube have a limit to the amount of video it buffers while watching it?

Tags: youtube, buffer

Suppose you are watching a video and you pause it for a while.

Does YouTube take the time to load as much as possible?

There's a good chance all that data gets wasted.

Is there a way to limit it?

Comment: @DavidPostill, I actually have wondered this myself. Where *should* this question be asked in order to *not* be off topic? I know there's a webapp stack exchange where YouTube questions might be more appropriate, but I assumed the question was more about the mobile YouTube apps in general where data charges would usually be a concern. And, the webapp stack exchange details specifically states smart phone apps are off topic there.  So, maybe the question should be clarified to indicate a specific platform and then moved to say Android?

Comment: @DavidWoodward Maybe. It is not clear.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidWoodward, I was about to mention the point. I probably wouldn't get a good answer if I asked this in a place like Yahoo Answers or reddit.